# Github API error when creating repo from CL with node, JSON parsing error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, github-api

Creating a node CLI to create repos from CL, having an issue posting to github api.  I'm using the request module to post to the github API.

```
request.post({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    headers:{
        'User-Agent': 'git CL - node', 
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    auth:{
        username: '-username-',
        password: '-password-'
    }, 
    form:{ 
        name: "a-new-repo" 
    }

}, function(err, res, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

The error I'm getting is `{"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"http://developer.github.com/v3"}`

I've tried a ton of things, like

- Setting multipart data
- body instead of form data
- Setting the content-type
- Sending as JSON

Things I know are correct

- authentication --- I'm able to get a correct response if i do a GET req, its just the POST
- POST path and headers

Link for [request-module](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

Link for [github-api](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `json` to the data you want to send, not `form`:

```
request.post({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    headers:{
        'User-Agent': 'git CL - node', 
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    auth:{
        username: '-username-',
        password: '-password-'
    }, 
    json:{ 
        name: "a-new-repo" 
    },
}, function(err, res, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter called `json` in the API docs, have you tried setting that to be `true`?

From my reading, this is what is necessary to send the form data as a JSON structure, rather than as form-encoded in the request body.

```
request.post({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    headers:{
        'User-Agent': 'git CL - node', 
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    auth:{
        username: '-username-',
        password: '-password-'
    }, 
    form:{ 
        name: "a-new-repo" 
    },
    json: true

}, function(err, res, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: I got the answer, instead of sending as a form, send it as json.

Comment: Could you provide an answer with a code snippet, for other people who are interested?

Comment: @ChrisAlexander look at the other answer